# What does the "pn" column mean in this pseudopotential file?

Tags: quantum-espresso, pseudopotentials, terminology

[image]

In this SSSP pseudopotential file for Quantum ESPRESSO, what does the "pn" column mean?

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Thank you for contributing your question here and we hope to see much more of you in the future !!! But can you please copy-and-paste the data into a `code` block rather than showing us a screenshot? The screenshot will not load in some browsers, especially on phones which have images blocked, and blind people who are using screen readers, won't be able to see what this is. Furthermore, data is less searchable when in this format.

Answer (score 5):

The "pn" column here gives the principal quantum number ("n") for the states of the pseudoatom, which is the "atom" that remains after the core electrons are removed and the original Coulomb potential is replaced with the pseudopotential.

For example, in the file you show, the $n=1$, $l=0$ state of the pseudo-atom corresponds to the $4S$ state ($n=4$, $l=0$) of the original all-electron atom.